# How to iterate over array of objects and change property in redux?

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux

**I have this array in my state:**

```
state:{     
   items:[{id:0},{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]
}
```

**I Am able to do this:**
 I can delete one of these objects, for example, the second one, the array is gonna be like this:

```
 items:[{id:0},{id:2},{id:3}]
```

**What I want to do (I need help to do it)**

I want to iterate over the array and set the id's equally to its own index position in the array, to become this:

```
 items:[{id:0},{id:1},{id:2}]
```

So, the objects with Id:2 and Id:3 would be set to Id:1 and Id:2 respectively, according to its new index position.

How can I Achieve it?

I am using the following code in the reducer to delete the desired object:

```
if(action.type==='deleteItem'){
    return{
        ...state,
        items:[
            ...state.items.slice(0,action.index),
            ...state.items.slice(action.index+1),
        ]

    }
}
```

How can I implement it to also change the Id properties in each object of the array, according to its new index position?

**Thank you all for the attention!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map over the resulting array after you remove one item, like this:

```
return {
    ...state,
    items: [
        ...state.items.slice(0,action.index),
        ...state.items.slice(action.index + 1),
    ].map((item, index) => ({ ...item, id: index }))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! There is a mistype in your answer though, that second parenthesis after the map argument is not needed. (:

Comment: @RogerPeixoto You're right, I typed this without actually running the code haha. I'll edit it just in case anyone stumbles upon this answer in the future. Glad it worked though :)